# Extract text with newline

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this pattern

```
const string ptnBodytext = @"<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>";
```

in order to extract the text within the `<p>` tags. It works fine except for those text with newline, e.g.:

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum
    second line or
    third one?
</p>
```

How can I change the pattern in order to include newline, tabs and so on?

Comment: If you are parsing HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Well, why not use `.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to activate the dotall mode or:

```
const string ptnBodytext = @"<p>([\s\S]+?)</p>";
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yG5hW3/2).

Comment: `const string ptnBodytext = @"<p>(.+?)</p>";`  and pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline`  flag when building the regex object.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `\s*`:

```
const string ptnBodytext = @"<p>(.+?)</p>";
```

Comment: [**Not** true](https://regex101.com/r/yG5hW3/1) without [`DOTALL`](https://regex101.com/r/yG5hW3/2) mode. Additionally, `\s*` matches *zero* or more whitespace characters.